# Assign array element to a variable, then modify array element by modify variable but don't work

Tags: javascript, swap

So I want to do expression on variable instead of directly array element because I think

1. The compiler will re-calculate to find the array element
2. Naming variable is easy to understand than arr[idx]

But when I attempt to swap 2 element in the array using variable, it don't work (see the code below).

I can't think of the keyword to this situation. Google results are all deep/shallow copy array.

Any explanation?

```js
for (let i = 0, j = 1; i < numsClone.length && j < numsClone.length;) {
    let numHasEvenIdx = numsClone[i];
    let numHasOddIdx = numsClone[j];

    if (numHasEvenIdx % 2 === 1 && numHasOddIdx % 2 === 0) {
      [numsClone[i], numsClone[j]] = [numsClone[j], numsClone[i]]; 
      // I want this to be [numHasEvenIdx, numHasOddIdx] = [numHasOddIdx, numHasEvenIdx]
      i += 2;
      j += 2;
    }
    else if (numHasEvenIdx % 2 === 0) i += 2;
    else j += 2; //(numHasOddIdx % 2 === 1)

}
```

Comment: 1. Array assignments are references, not copies. 2. Your expected outcome is unclear. You start with independent arrays in your loop, but the loop construct nested arrays. Can you please provide "before" and "after" views of your data?

Comment: I don't see any nested arrays in my loop @RandyCasburn

Comment: yes - I mis-read your assignment statement. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That's why I prefer named variable hehe